# Font-Awesome in WordPress - Icons not stacking correctly

Tags: wordpress, fonts, icons, font-awesome

I am using Font-Awesome in a WordPress site have included the Font-Awesome CDN in my functions.php file according to [this bit of php](http://youneedfat.com/font-awesome-wordpress-cdn/).

I can insert the icons into my site but am unable to get icons to stack according to this example code:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
fa-twitter on fa-square-o
```

You can see the output of this code [here](http://dariusdevas.com/wp/?page_id=79).

Does anyone have any thoughts on why this may not be working? I'm pretty sure that there are no CSS class clashes...

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing view source on your page:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><br />
  <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i><br />
  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i><br />
</span>
```

The `<br />` elements are breaking Font Awesome's CSS. I imagine WordPress is putting those in automatically for you, so try putting everything on one line so WordPress doesn't try to add any `<br />` elements into the code:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg"><i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
```

Comment: David! You're a legend :-D!

It worked... Pretty obvious now that you mention it, but I am pretty new to all of this and it's great to learn some of the tricks for troubleshooting these problems. Many many thanks :-)